# How to center text inside a SVG g element?

Tags: css, svg

I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/e4bAh/. But it's only centered horizontally. This is the code and JSFiddle:

```
  <svg width="400" height="400">
    <g class="point" transform="translate(225,217)">
      <circle></circle>
      <text class="pointIndex" y="50">
        <tspan text-anchor="middle">10</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>

 <style>
    .point circle {
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      fill: #E2137E;
      r: 10;
      stroke: #333;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
 </style>
```

How to center `.pointIndex` inside `.point`?

https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/9a112b63/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally the issue was with `y="50"` in the `text.pointIndex` , change it to `y="5"` to get it vertically centered

[**JS Fiddle** - *updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9a112b63/8/)

```css
.point circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  fill: #E2137E;
  r: 10;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g class="point" transform="translate(225,217)">
    <circle></circle>
    <text class="pointIndex" y="5">
      <tspan text-anchor="middle">10</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Since there are numbers from 1 to 10. I need to find a non-pixel way of centering them.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to add the updated version of the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/9a112b63/4/

Comment: why do you have `transform="translate(100)"` on the `text.class="pointIndex"` is it necessary?

Comment: I took that from the other fiddle, but I think it's not necessary.

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks. (By the way, why `transform:translateY(-45px)`?

Comment: it needs to be shifted up by almost the height of the circle which is **`50px`** but if you did **`50px`** the top of the text will appear at same top point of the circle so just shift it down a little to get it centered.

Comment: I see but weird, the radius of the circle is 10px and it's stroke 2px. Shouldn't the circle be 44px high then?

Comment: No it is my fault it is not the circle, it is the `y=50` in the text, just make it `y="5"` and no need for CSS https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9a112b63/8/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline set the baseline to middle to center the text properly vertical.

Comment: @seahorsepip would you please show me this implemented in a fiddle? for this case I mean

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/9a112b63/9/ Here you go, I made the circle bigger to show the magic of the baseline property :P

Comment: Keep in mind this attribute does not work on all elements, there's another attribute that does the same for other elements, see the mozilla article ^^

Comment: Nice, I rarely work with SVG so I don't know many attributes and sure with this attribute it is easier and more appropriate since yo udon't need to make calculations yourself, post it as an answer mate